# Can't connect to apex, after succsessiful instalation

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I've installed Oracle Apex on local machine, following this steps - [LINK](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-installation)
I used Embedded PL/SQL Gateway (EPG) Configuration.

And when I try to connect on http://localhost:8080/apex I get - unable to connect firefox message. I checked firewall is inactive

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've followed all the steps and you're installing on windows, check if the OracleJobScheduler service is running (it will be postfixed with the instance name). You can do this by searching for Component Services in the windows search bar, then open the Services (Local). If the scheduler job service is not running then start it, wait a few moments, and try to re-connect.

Comment: Article which I followed is on Oracle Linux 7

Comment: Aha, I followed the same article 3 days ago to install APEX on windows and everything worked fine hence the question. I haven't peformed an install on Linux in the last 6 months, but it worked fine when I did.